# 3d plots for neural network

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize the optimal region where X represents the number of layers, Y represents the number of epochs and Z represents the Mean Percent Error by plotting 3D surface plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
## Defining X, Y, Z for the 3d plot
# X represents the number of layers

X = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

# Y represents the number of epochs 

Y = [10,20,30,50,100,200,300,400,500,600]

# Z represents Mean Percent Error
# itertools will be used to show how Z will look like 
import itertools
Z = ['10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1']
# Possible combinations of 10 numbers
Z_1 = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(Z,10))
print(Z_1)
```

So for each # layers, there is a corresponding 10 different # of epochs and there are 10 corresponding Z which means Z will be a list of strings and each list has 10 elements in it.

After that, I have tried

```
# Reshaping the data

x = np.reshape(X, (10))
y = np.reshape(Y, (10))
z = np.reshape(Z, (660, 1))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x,y,z)
ax.set_xlabel('Number of Layers')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Epochs')
ax.set_zlabel('% Error')

ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Any help with where to start? what to fix?

Your help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the variable `O`?

Comment: @Anwarvic I edited the variable O, it was a typo it is Z instead.

Comment: In the question, you said `Z` is a list of list... but all I can see is a list of strings. Also, `Z` can't be reshaped into this shape

Comment: I have edited to strings. How should I start to solve this problem? I want to visualize the optimal region meaning low percent error region.